# MongoImport csv combine/concat various columns to one array for import

Tags: javascript, mongodb, csv, mongoose, mongoimport

I have another interesting case which I have never faced before, so I'm asking help from SO community and also share my experience with it.

> The case || What we have:

1. A `csv` file (exported from other SQL DB) with such structure
   (headers):

   `ID,SpellID,Reagent[0],Reagent[1..6]Reagent[7],ReagentCount[0],ReagentCount[1..6],ReagentCount[7]`

   You could also check a full `-csv` data file here, [at my
   dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgdc0vyp5m7vsqr/eva.csv)
2. [My gist from Github](https://gist.github.com/AlexZeDim/089886531a889d4ff31098fb396308bf), which helps you to understand how `MongoImport` works.

> What we need:

I'd like to receive such structure(schema) to import it into `MongoDB` collection:

```
ID(Number),SpellID(Number),Reagent(Array),ReagentCount(Array)
6,898,[878],[1]
```

with ID, SpellID, and two arrays, in first we store all Reagent IDs, like [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] from all `Reagent[n]` columns, and in the second array we have the array with the same length that represent `quantity` of ReagentIDs, from all `ReagentCount[n]`

**OR**

A transposed objects with such structure (schema):

```
ID(Number),SpellID(Number),ReagentID(Number),Quantity/Count(Number)
80,2675,1,2
80,2675,134,15
80,2675,14,45
```

As you may see, the difference between the first example and this one, that every document in the collection represents each `ReagentID` and it's quantity to `SpellID`. So if one `Spell_ID` have `N` different reagents it will be `N` documents in the collection, cause we all know, that there can't be more then 7 unique `Reagent_ID` belonging to one `Spell_ID` according to our `-csv` file.

> I am working on this problem right now, with the help of `node js` and `npm i csv` (or any other modules for parsing `csv` files). Just to make my `csv` file available for importing to my DB via `mongoose`. I'll be very thankful for all those, who could provide any relevant contribution to this case. But anyway, I will solve this problem eventually and share my solution in this question.
>
> As for the first variant I guess there should be one-time script for MongoImport that could concat all columns from `Reagent[n]` & `ReagentCount[n]` to two separate arrays like I mentioned above, via -fields but unfortunately I don't know it, and there are no examples on SO or official Mongo docs relevant to it. So if you have enough experience with `MongoImport` feel free to share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve my problem as I want it to, but without using `mongoimport`

I used `npm i csv` and write function for parsing my `csv` file. In short:

```
async function FuncName (path) {
    try {
        let eva = fs.readFileSync(path,'utf8');
        csv.parse(eva, async function(err, data) {
            //console.log(data[0]); we receive headers, if they exist
            for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { //we start from 1, because 0 is headers, if we don't have it, then we start from 0
                console.log(data[i][34]); //where i is row number and  j(34) is a header address
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

It loops over `csv` file and shows data in array that allows you to operate with them as you want it to.